# T-SQL: I need to fetch missed value in column of strings

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

In my query I need to find missed values in a string. My query returns the `code_grille_talend` and the number of missed values. Now, I need to fetch the missed values to complete my job

I have tried a query in SQL Server that returns the `code_grille_talend` that includes all values and the number of missed values

```
select top 1 
    (G.[code_grille_talend]),
    count(C.code) as counter 
from 
    [dbo].[code] G
left join    
    [dbo].[codeT] C on G.code_grille_talend not like '%' + LTRIM(RTRIM(C.code)) + '%'
group by 
    G.code_grille_talend
having 
    len(g.code_grille_talend) + count(C.code) <= 20 or count(C.code) = 0
order by 
    len(g.code_grille_talend) desc
```

This query returns the top1 code grille and the number of missed values. now, if c.count>0 (1,2,etc.). I need to know which value ( code ) is missed.

the code like 1,2,4,7
and the code_grille_talend like 147582, 26854789, 2579365, 478529

Answer (score 0):

If you have a table with required codes and a table with the actual codes, you can see which required codes are missing by using the query below.

```
CREATE TABLE #requiredValues ([Code] VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO
    #requiredValues
VALUES
    ('1'),
    ('2')

CREATE TABLE #values ([Code] VARCHAR(MAX))
INSERT INTO
    #values
VALUES
    ('12'),
    ('2'),
    ('3')

SELECT
    #values.[Code], STRING_AGG(#requiredValues.[Code], ', ')
FROM
    #requiredValues
RIGHT JOIN
    #values ON #values.[Code] NOT LIKE '%' + #requiredValues.[Code] + '%'
GROUP BY
    #values.[Code]

-- Without STRING_AGG: for SQL versions pre-2017.
SELECT
    #values.[Code]
    ,STUFF((
        SELECT
            ', ' + #requiredValues.[Code]
        FROM
            #requiredValues
        WHERE
            #values.[Code] NOT LIKE '%' + #requiredValues.[Code] + '%'
        FOR XML PATH ('')),1,2,'')
FROM
    #values
GROUP BY
    #values.[Code]

DROP TABLE #requiredValues
DROP TABLE #values
```